# Check each channel in a category for specific topic

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How can I check every channel in a category for a specific topic?

e.g `if(channel.topic == "Test")`

I've already tried to ask in other servers, but couldn't get enough help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can `.fetch()` a category channel by its ID. It returns a promise so you need to await the results. [Category channels](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CategoryChannel) have a `children` property. It's a collection of the channels that are a part of this category.

On a collection you can `.filter()` the results to return every channel that has a topic of "test":

```js
const CATEGORY_ID = '813845580217434931';

const { children } = await client.channels.fetch(CATEGORY_ID);
const channelsWithTestTopic = children.filter((ch) => ch.topic === 'test');

console.log(channelsWithTestTopic);
```

You can also use the `.each()` method and do something if the topic is "test":

```js
const { children } = await client.channels.fetch(CATEGORY_ID);

children.each((ch) => {
  if (ch.topic === 'test') {
    console.log(ch.name);
  }
});
```